Minecraft Lunar Client App Image won't start
Hi I'm trying to install Lunar Client for Minecraft.
I downloaded the latest file Lunar Client-3.2.17-ow.AppImage made it executable in property's and it wont start. I get no errors.
Im running Ubuntu 24.04 off a live USB with persistence.
Any help would be appreciated.
